# What are some professional sentences one can use to quit their job?

Tags: sentence-choice, sentence-usage

Let's say someone works at a restaurant as a waiter. What are some appropriate sentences they could use to tell their manager that they'd like to leave their job?

Comment: Should potentially be asked on the [Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) exchange.

Comment: @Bee or just search on that SE site.  I'm sure the question has been asked and answered many times.

Comment: @Andrew very true, it probably has

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately, I would like to **tender my resignation.**

Or

> I wish to resign.